# Pass argument to pub function from React sub in Meteor?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am publishing all my comments collection with this:

```
Meteor.publish('comments', function() {
  return Comments.find(
    {},
    { fields: { date: 1, body: 1, user: 1, attachedTo: 1, attachedToID: 1 } },
  );
});
```

And subscribing in a React component with this:

```
export default withTracker(() => {
  let commentsSub = Meteor.subscribe('comments');
  return {
    comments: Comments.find({}).fetch(),
  };
})(MyReactComponent);
```

So far this works but now I want to refine what comments are sent. The attachedTo field for comments can be either 'profile' or 'homepage'. Ive modified my pub function to take an input:

```
Meteor.publish('comments', function(attachedTo) {
  return Comments.find(
    { attachedTo: attachedTo },
    { fields: { date: 1, body: 1, user: 1, attachedTo: 1, attachedToID: 1 } },
  );
});
```

But I cant see how to pass this parameter from my React component:

```
export default withTracker(() => {
  let commentsSub = Meteor.subscribe('comments');
  return {
    comments: Comments.find({ attachedTo: 'group' }).fetch(),
  };
})(MyReactComponent);
```

Comment: In your current implementation, ```attachTo``` in the publish function will be undefined since you are not passing it any argument. ```let commentsSub = Meteor.subscribe('comments','group');```  You are going to have to pass 'group' as the argument to the publish function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current implementation, attachTo in the publish function will be undefined since you are not passing it any argument.

**Subscriptions:**

```
...
let commentsSub = Meteor.subscribe('comments','group'); // pass the value to the publish function.
...
```

You are going to have to pass 'group' as the argument to the publish function.

Answer (score 0):

Ive expanded on blueren's answer as I wanted to have named parameters:

```
export default withTracker(() => {
  let commentsSub = Meteor.subscribe('comments', { attachedTo: 'profile' });
  return {
    comments: Comments.find({}).fetch(),
  };
})(MyReactComponent);

Meteor.publish('comments', function(attachedTo) {
  return Comments.find(
    { attachedTo },
    { fields: { date: 1, body: 1, user: 1, attachedTo: 1, attachedToID: 1 } },
  );
});
```

Comment: Small note : ```{ attachedTo: 'profile' }``` -- you're passing the object. Your publish function will now look like: ```Comments.find(
    { attachedTo: {attachedTo: 'profile'} }, .....``` I believe you only need to pass the value, or change the find query to ```Comments.find(
    attachedTo, {fields.....})```